# Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key AppBarButtonStyle

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Common style included in winrt are getting me an exception

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}" />
```

this basic code fires `Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key AppBarButtonStyle` exception

Common resources are included in my app.xaml and I can navigate through the definition of this style..

Am I missing something really big here?

ps: I've tried restarting VS

Answer (score 2):

我遇到这个问题是在一个单独的资源字典里定义

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}" />
```

如果将其放到某个页面的xmal内部的resource里，OK。

我解决这个问题是在资源字典头部添加

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Common/StandardStyles.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Comment: Any chance you could provide this in English?

Comment: Translation: I encountered this problem is defined in a separate resource dictionary <code>. If you put it in the resource inside XAML of a certain page, OK. I solved this problem by adding in the resource dictionary header <more code>.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 8.1 the StandardStyles.xaml file which contained the AppBarButtonStyle has been removed. Instead you can use the AppBarButton as shown here:

```html
<AppBarButton Icon="Play" Label="Play" />
```

Check this article by Tim Heuer:
http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2013/10/29/remove-standardstyles-xaml-from-windows-8-1-winrt-projects.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here are your three possible reasons:

1. Is /Common/StandardStyles.xaml still there ?
2. Is AppBarButtonStyle still in /Common/StandardStyles.xaml ?
3. Does App.xaml still reference /Common/StandardStyles.xaml ?

App.xaml should look something like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Common/StandardStyles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by defining the AppBarButtonStyle before my customized styles that extend AppBarButtonStyle.